# Why is 3 the only public exponent accepted for Android platform.key?

Tags: android, rsa

I am building an android system.

I have an existing key pair, with a public exponent F4 (65537).

I try to use it as platform.key (I have the pk8 and the x509).

During the build process, DumpPublicKey is called on my key pair.

At this point, the key is rejected because the public exponent is not 3. (I checked in the code of DumpPublicKey, it is exactly what it does: compare with 3 and reject otherwise)

Here is the stacktrace for this :

```
java.lang.Exception: Public exponent should be 3 but is 65537.
    at com.android.dumpkey.DumpPublicKey.check(DumpPublicKey.java:75)
    at com.android.dumpkey.DumpPublicKey.main(DumpPublicKey.java:151)
```

Does this means I have to generate a new key pair using

```
openssl genrsa -3 ...
```

or is there any way I can still use my key?

Also, why is it so important that the public exponent is 3 and not F4?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using 3 instead of 65537 allows signature verification to be as much as 8 times faster.

Comment: Thank you GregS. That is about what I though. Do you now if there is a way to have android accept my key?

Comment: sorry, I don't know much about Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in com.android.dumpkey.DumpPublicKey to me.
Restricting the the public exponent of an RSA key to 3 is just plain silly.
Doing so just makes it more likely that implementation errors have desastrous effects,
if the underlying library is not implemented correctly.

As far as I know Android uses Bouncycastle, which is a crypto library that is
not carefully implemented.

Using the standard exponent 2^16+1 as you do, is very reasonable and avoids many potential
problems with small exponents.

Comment: I removed the exception part in DumpPublicKey and it appears to work (so far)